# Change Image URL Dynamically in .ascx page from .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, image, user-controls

I am having the Usercontrol page (.ascx) which having the Header image for the site. I need to change the Header image dynamically in the webform(.aspx) .

MY .Aspx Code :

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control hdrCtl = null;
   try
   {                               
       hdrCtl = LoadControl("~/UI/Header.ascx");
       if (hdrCtl != null)
       {    
           Image src = (Image)hdrCtl.FindControl("imgHeader");                                     
           src.ImageUrl = "~/Content/assets/images/editorial_1.jpg";
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Trace.Write(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

but the image Did not changed...Can anyone help me to figure out the problem..

Thanks in advance

Vijay

Comment: Put a break point to the line where u changing the image and see if it is reached?

Comment: hi kaf I did that.It is showing the updated ImagePath while debugging but is not displayed in webpage.. i have checked the Image Path all are fine but didnot know why the updated image didnot displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is that you load your control **again** and with out add in it in the page at the line:

```
hdrCtl = LoadControl("~/UI/Header.ascx");
```

To make the code work as it is, its missing the `Page.Controls.Add(hdrCtl)` but I do not think that is the way you make it.

I understand that your control all ready exist in your page, so this is not the way to change the image.
To change the images on your custom control that you have all ready add on your page you have to create a parameter to the image inside your custom control as:

```
public string cHeaderImage
{
  set { imgHeader.ImageUrl = value; }
}
```

and then you simple do

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // this is the id of your custom control
  headerCntrID.cHeaderImage = "~/Content/assets/images/editorial_1.jpg";
}
```

Comment: hi Aristos It is not working I have done a property as you explained when debugging it is showing the updated Imagepath but it didnot display the image and in firebug the imageurl property is not updated...

Comment: @VijayMathew Maybe its need to move it to PageLoad or to PageInit. You can also debug it to see if at the end of the page cycle the image have been change to that and you do not change it some where else on your code. Work with this idea a little and it will work.